# Daniel 9:27 - how to compute "half the week"?

Tags: revelation, daniel

> And he shall make a strong covenant with many for one week, and for
> half of the week he shall put an end to sacrifice and offering. And on
> the wing of abominations shall come one who makes desolate, until the
> decreed end is poured out on the desolator.”

"The week" is the set of seven (Jewish) years.
A Jewish year goes from Tishri-1 to Tishri-1 unless it precedes a Jubilee year and so starts on Tishri-10.

How does one calculate "half" of the week?

1. The midpoint of the 7 in terms of days
   i.e. last day of the seventh **minus** first day of the first
   divided by 2
   and add it to the first day of the first
2. Go to the 4th year and take the midpoint in terms of the number of days

Comment: In Old Testament judaism,  the years start in Nisan, not Tishrei. After the Exile, jews adopted the Babylonian names for the months and the Babylonian convention of starting the year in Tishrei and then later the metonic (Greek) calendar, but still the biblical year starts on the new moon 1 Nisan after the vernal equinox (absent leap months), and 1 Tishrei is just a new moon on which trumpets are blown.

Comment: @Robert please provide link for this.

Comment: @Robert but even if true, the 70th week is last 7 before Millenium so start of year still might be Tishrei in end times context?

Comment: A link would be Ex 12.2 and the rest of the law. You can use wikipedia or study history of jewish calendar. The 70th week would be right after the 69th week. If you take the 70th week and move it away from the 69th, there is no point in numbering the weeks.